# How To Use Javascript Variable In html attribute string

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am New to This

I am writing this code

"OnClientClick="return OpenRadWindow('ImportSDS.aspx?id=##', 'RWImport');" >

i have js variable 
var id = "<%=this.id %>";

So I want to Use This id Varable at ## How It Is Possible Please Help.

Comment: Can you please share your code in jsfiddle or snippet?

Comment: well, what is stopping you from writing `OpenRadWindow('ImportSDS.aspx?id=<%=this.id%>', 'RWImport')`? The `<%=%>` can spit the value in HTML as well as it is doing in JS part of the page.

Comment: <%=this.id%> Passing Null Value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the variable available, you should just use it in the method instead.

I don't have enough of your code really to go on but something like this.

```
function OpenRadWindow(url, x) { 
   var id = "<%= this.id %>";
   url = url + id;
   ... then your code here
}
```

Then for your `OnClientClick`

```
OnClientClick="return OpenRadWindow('ImportSDS.aspx?id=', 'RWImport');"
```

Comment: But I think  OpenRadWindow('ImportSDS.aspx?id=', 'RWImport');" Is Some Ajax Control